# Angular and C# single page project question

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I am starting to build my first c#/Angular project in VS2022. So far my layout is like this

[image]

Index.html contains the startup page with header, menu and footer code etc.
It also has this

```
<main-root></main-root>
```

Which merges in the code in main.component.html as expected.

This is main.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-root',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html'
})

export class MainComponent {
  title = 'TestPage';
}
```

And this is main.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { MainComponent } from './main.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [MainComponent]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

So this all compiles and runs fine, so what I want to do next is when a user clicks the correct button on the web page main-root is replaced with grid-root and that section of index.html is refreshed.

Can anyone show me how to achieve this please.

Thanks in advance

Kev

Comment: This is purely angular. No c# related, although you might have a c# backend. Consider removing the tag.

Comment: I suggest you take a [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes). It's a brief tutorial with the basic of Angular

Comment: Thanks, that tutorial was very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An angular app has to have a single component for the app to take place in, and in your project that is the `<main-root>` which is hosted in `index.html`.  You cannot and should not replace this element, it won't really work.  Keep in mind that the entire point of an Angular app is to have the content change without needing to refresh the page.

Instead here's what I'd suggest.  The default is to have an `<app-root>` element.  Use that, or something like that, as a main wrapping element.  Then inside of that you have have your two main elements with logic to show one or the other:

`index.html`

```html
<app-root></app-root>
```

And then inside of that App Root component you can have your two "main/grid" components with show/hide logic or whatever you need

```html
<app-main *ngIf="!showGrid"></app-main>
<app-grid *ngIf="showGrid"></app-grid>
```